# Magento Multishop with 2 domains - how to block one from Google?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I am running a Magento 1.9.2.1 instance with 2 domains configured. One of them should not be reached by Google. How could I block that domain from the instance but allow the other for Google? Both domains should be fully accessible by the user and the admin.

I only have one htaccess in my root folder, so I am not using the one folder per domain way to run my multi shop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block Google through your robots.txt file. You can specify the robots file for each domain through each domains sitemap.xml.

This guide here should help with the setup without using the sitemap file: http://www.infinitecodeworks.com/how-to-serve-robots-txt-file-for-multi-store-magento-setup/